# HTML Access only camera and not gallery for iOS user

Tags: android, html, ios, iphone

So I have tried accessing only the camera and not the gallery with this html code from my web app.

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
```

which works fine for Android but not for iOS. The iOS user is granted with the option of choosing a photo from the gallery which is something I don't want. I have read here that it is simply not possible.

Before you mark it as a duplicate I want you to know that I am asking because the previous question was asked 4 years ago.

So I was wondering, has anything changed from then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question do not tell us what we need to solve your problem. Are you using a simulator to test it? What kind of framework are you using?

Comment: I have a website running and I have tested it on android and ios devices, not emulators. Maybe I need to rephrase. Is there a way to access only the camera and not the gallery of an iOS device in html?

Comment: Did you try to set the `capture` attribute to `camera`? Like this `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

Comment: Yes have tried that as well... No luck unfortunately...